# Add search filter in an Observable array

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am currently working on angular 5 and firestore. I have an observable array **activities** which have a fields of collection of firestore. I am catching the fields of firestore as:

```
   activities: Observable<any[]>;
    this.activities = this.afs.collection('activities').valueChanges();
```

and there is table which shows the values of activities:

```
 <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Section</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Max Players</th>
       <th >Locked</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let activity of activities | async >

               <td>
                 {{activity.section}}

               </td>
               <td >
                 {{activity.name}}
               </td>
               <td>
               {{activity.maxPlayers}}
             </td>

               <td>
                 {{activity.locked}}
               </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
```

Now i want to add functionality of search method by  activity.name. I followed so many tutorials for filtering but nothing works.I am new to angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in client side with angular `pipes`

First generate a pipe

```
ng g pipe pipes/activityfilter
```

here `pipes/` is the directory, you can name it any. If you are not using `angular cli` you have to create it manually. Now your `activityfilter.pipe.ts` should look like this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'activityfilter'
})
export class ActivityfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(activities: any, term?: any): any {
    if( term === undefined) return activities;
    return activities.filter(function(activity){
      return activity.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());
    })
  }
}
```

Now define `term:string;` in your `component.ts` class

And in your html add an input and bind to `term`

```
<input name="search"  type="text" placeholder="Search..."  [(ngModel)]="term"> 

<table class="table">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Section</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Max Players</th>
   <th >Locked</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let activity of activities | async | activityfilter:term>

           <td>
             {{activity.section}}

           </td>
           <td >
             {{activity.name}}
           </td>
           <td>
           {{activity.maxPlayers}}
         </td>

           <td>
             {{activity.locked}}
           </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: It works perfect. Thanks for your help man. You are really amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is queries, to search on the server rather than client:

```
const joggings = 
    this.afs.collection('activities', ref => ref.where('name', '==', 'jogging'))
    .valueChanges();
```

Refer to [angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) for what more you can do with queries.

However, to filter an array in an observable result on client side, one way would be using the map operator and Array.prototype.filter:

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
const joggings = 
    this.afs.collection('activities')
    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(
        map(items => items.filter(item => item.name === 'jogging'))
    )
```